# Why are N/As introduced by coercion when I make a variable numeric?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to convert a variable to numeric by this code:

```
Joined1[,"utility.x"]<-as.numeric(as.character(Joined1[,"utility.x"]))
```

It makes all columns N/A.

```
b<-dput(Joined1[1:2,17:20])
structure(list(utipassen.x = c(0.219353162283623, 0.219353162283623
), mode.x = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    utility.x = c(4.02748247217461, 4.02748247217461), new.x = c(2, 
    2)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Please, let me know if you need to see my data. And as you can see in the code, I want to make `utility.x` numeric.

Comment: Isn't `utility.x` already numeric? `class(b$utility.x) #[1] "numeric"`

Comment: It's likely you have a string that's not convertible to numeric in `utility.x`. It doesn't show in your sample data, though. Try `unique(Joined1$utility.x)` and see if you can pinpoint the value causing the problem. As an aside note, the pronoun is **you**, not _u_.

Answer (score 1):

If you print
`Joined1[,"utility.x"]`, you will see that the result is a tibble, taking `as.character` on this leads to unexpected results (this is because `Joined1`is a tibble, if you had an object of class `data.frame`only your code should work)

However, `Joined1$utility.x` is a vector, so you can do

```
Joined1$utility.x <- as.numeric(as.character(Joined1$utility.x))
```